# Error when using LSH index in opencv::flann

Tags: c++, opencv, flann

I'm trying to use LSH implementation of flann in opencv:

```
const int mySizes[1]={100};
cv::Mat descriptors1 = cv::Mat::zeros(1,mySizes,CV_32F);
cv::Mat descriptors2 = cv::Mat::zeros(1,mySizes,CV_32F);

cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher_;
matcher_ = new cv::FlannBasedMatcher(new cv::flann::LshIndexParams(20,10,2));
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
matcher_->match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

std::cout << matches[0].distance << std::endl;
```

more precisely i want to obtain the LSH distance between `descriptors1` and `descriptors2` using `matches[0].distance`.

But when i run this code i get:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=5
) in buildIndex_, file /home/lpuglia/repository/opencv/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 315
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/lpuglia/repository/opencv/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:315: error: (-210) type=5
 in function buildIndex_
```

The code is pretty simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is related: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5937

Answer (score 0):

Was using the wrong descritptor type, solution:

```
cv::UMat descriptors1 = cv::UMat (1, 100, CV_8UC1);
cv::UMat descriptors2 = cv::UMat (1, 100, CV_8UC1);
```